# Constructing 1-Radian.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

The definition of 1-radian is stated as:

"The measure of an angle subtended at the center of a circle by an **arc of length equal to the radius** of the circle"

How can I rigorously construct an arc of length equal to the radius of the circle using geometry?

Comment: If you could construct $1$ radian, that would make $e^i$ constructible, and hence algebraic. It is not.

Comment: I do not know that. In every school level book, I see this definition. But there is nothing mentioned about its construction. Since the idea is very fundamental I thought to know about it properly.

Comment: Well, you can't construct it.

Comment: Whaat did you mean by "construct" here?  Usually, in speaking of Euclidean Geometry, that word refers to construction by straight edge and compass, and with that definition, an angle equal to $1$ radian is not constructible.  But perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: Can you suggest to me something, which I can read on this?

Comment: @lulu I meant constructing my straight edge and compass. Can we prove, that it cannot be constructed?

Comment: It works the same way with a right angle of $90^\circ$ subtending an arc of $\pi/2$. You can't construct a line segment of length $\pi/2$ even though you can construct a right angle.

Comment: Of course, it follows at once from the point  @DonThousand made.  Any of the standard references on construction by straight edge and compass should include a discussion of the relation between constructible and algebraic numbers.

Comment: The construction of $1$ radian directly leads to the construction of $\cos(1)$ and $\sin(1)$ by the unit circle definition, and both of these are non-algebraic and thus non-constructible.

Comment: @lulu: Can you tell me a book or any article where I can read about this explicitly.

Comment: [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Polya/00494925.di020681.02p0432j.pdf) is a reference.